# Socket.io "io is undefined"

Tags: socket.io

I have a problem with socket.io. I load the server file,

```
require("socket.io").listen(801);
```

and press a button on my html,

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
function doSocket() {
io.connect("serverHost:801");
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="doSocket()">
```

and I get the error, "io is not defined."

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're running the socket.io server on port 801, you need to request the client file from that port as well:

```
<script src="http://serverHost:801/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I would have never figured that out. There is no information anywhere that led me to believe that was true.

Comment: @LogicalAngel the example code on the website uses port 80, which hides the fact that the server also serves the client-side code. I agree it's confusing.